# Regex Matching First Two Characters Followed by a Space

Tags: regex

I need some help with a regular expression to match strings that begin with the characters EN followed by a space.

I have tried `'^EN '`

But it wont match the the trailing space. Is there away to force it to match only strings beginning with 'EN ' and not just containing it and include the trailing space in the match.

Comment: what regexp flavour are you using?

Comment: Which language/method are you using? Are the quotes part of the expression? Could you please provide some matching and non-matching examples? Have you had a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/?

Comment: Your regex should work http://regexr.com?2vk74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^EN\s+
```

That'll match strings that start with `EN` followed by one or more space characters.

Answer (score 0):

At least in C#, you can try "^EN\s+"